# Using Turtlebot with basic DC motors

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im wondering if i can modify a Turtlebot3 burger to work with basic DC motors. Or at the very least i was wondering if i could use the HLS-LFCD2 lidar module with a standalone arduino board and DC motor shield

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287326/using--turtlebot-with-basic-dc-motors/) by [sneakycoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/34009/sneakycoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make the DC motors work with Turtlebot3 Burger using a Driver like L293D or L298N on the Raspi on board. However, you will need to manually create your own driver packages and calibrate them to work well with the Turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Akash Purandare](https://answers.ros.org/users/34280/akash-purandare/) with karma: 61 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0